# Usar Passport-facebook en una API rest en NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api, facebook, passport

Tengo  una aplicación hecha en **express**, hasta ahora usaba el mismo servidor para mostrar el HTML y demás. Ésta aplicación **tiene login con Facebook y funciona.**

Necesito saber cómo implementar el login de Facebook en una **API** para ser usado desde un **cliente** como una **aplicación móvil** o una aplicación de escritorio, sería de gran ayuda un tutorial o ejemplo pues he buscado y no encuentro algo así.
Gracias :D

Comment: No entiendo cuál es la duda en concreto, no hay diferencias notables en la lógica. ¿Has intentado hacerlo? Al abstraer todo en una API no importa qué cliente estás usando ya que todo lenguaje móvil, véase Java, Kotlin, Swift o JavaScript (mediante React Native), NativeScript, etc., tienen APIs para peticiones.

Comment: Hola, el problema es que passport-facebook usa dos urls (auth y callback)
cuando hay un GET a /auth/facebook se ejecuta la estrategia para FB y según entiendo FB hace un GET a /auth/facebook/callback y si hay éxito redirijo a una url que muestra un JSON con la información del perfil


Si intento hacerlo con un simple GET de Jquery obtengo esto 

Una captura de mi intento con jquery  https://k60.kn3.net/0/8/9/E/2/A/57C.png